# ClickOnce deployed application asks to install update even if there exists none

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, clickonce

I have ClickOnce deployed application coded in C#. I wonder if anyone experienced the same problem.

Clickonce deployed application checks for updates always before execution. One of my clients using this application informs me about an update which the application asks to install even if there exists no update we had deployed. My clients installed the update. But what was installed is the same version. At this point, I wonder why a clickonce application decides if there is an update deployed. I believe this is a weird problem that I could not figure out why it happened.

Is there anyone who knows why such a weird thing could happen ? I suspect may be some of files of the installation removed, thus leading a reinstallation of the program. But I am not sure.

Comment: Have you checked the version of the application? Unless and untill version is updated, clickonce doesn't prompt for new version.

Comment: I had installed the latest deployed version to the clients machine months ago. The latest deployed version and clients installed version matches. Even if this is the case, the clickonce mysteriously asked to update the installation.

Answer (score 2):

We've had this problem before with some of our clients. The problem ended up being due to object caching on their proxy server. Basically, the client **actually *is* running an old version**, so when they start your program, ClickOnce correctly reports that there is an update available. The problem is that the client's proxy server caches an old copy of your program, so when the updater runs the proxy server intercepts the update request and instead sends back a cached copy of your program in place of the update. ClickOnce doesn't notice until its next startup that the "updated" program still isn't actually updated.

The solution is to get in touch with your client's IT staff and try to figure out where the caching is happening and have them clear the cache. It's probably on their custom-built proxy server, but webfilters like [Barracuda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barracuda_Networks#Products) do object caching too, and so do some of the fancier Cisco routers.

Comment: This may be the case if there is an update deployed. Let me clarify; client had version 1.0.0 installed. The lastest version deployed by us is version 1.0.0. Even though the situation is as I have expressed, clickonce warned the user about an update. This is the point what I could not understand. However, I believe, it may be due  to a change in client's IT infrastructure configuration.